# REST public content type

Tags: 8

I have a REST View with unrestricted access using the fields format. My custom fields are returned correctly for anonymous users, but the content type is empty as in the following example.

```
[
  {
    field_custom_1: "Hello",
    type: ""
  }
]
```

The only solution I found is giving the *View published content* permission to the anonymous user, but then anyone can can see details I don't want to be public.

Comment: Could you show an example of the output of your View ?

Comment: Please, i would need more. I think this issue is related with field configuration in Views. When you select the field, it opens a popup with the lots of setting. I would need the list of the checked settings in this screen. Are you sure that you are not overwritting the result ?

Comment: @Rufein it's a fresh view, when the View published content is on then it works when it's off then it doesn't

Comment: Sorry, i have understood that you want to hide some fields. Is it correct ?

Comment: No exactly the opposite. I want to display the Content-Type